# MPAndroidChart groupBars() "interval per group" calculation formula

Tags: mpandroidchart

The official [documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/setting-data/) for MPAndroidChart's Grouped BarChart gives the following formula for "interval per group":

```
float groupSpace = 0.06f;
float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
float barWidth = 0.45f; // x2 dataset
// (0.02 + 0.45) * 2 + 0.06 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"
```

However, since *barSpace*s are only between the bars, there will be one less *barSpace* than the number of bars/datasets and therefore the formula should be:

```
// barWidth * datasets + barSpace * (datasets - 1) + groupSpace == 1.00
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so after a little bit of investigation, it looks like there's 1/2 of *barSpace* around each bar and therefore, there're as many *barSpaces* as bars. However, that also means the true space between the groups is *groupSpace + barSpace*, since each *groupSpace* is also surrounded by 2 halves of a *barSpace*.

NOTE: if the officially documented formula doesn't equal to one, then the bar groups and labels will start drifting more and more away from each other. The chart should check it and report it as error, IM(not so)HO.